# Will CLR check the whole inheritance chain to determine which virtual method to call?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

The inheritance chain is as follows:

```
class A
    {
        public virtual void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A's method");
        }
    }

class B:A
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B's method");
        }
    }

class C:B
    {
        public new virtual void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C's method");
        }
    }

class D:C
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D's method");
        }
    }
```

then:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A tan = new D();
            tan.Foo();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

The result is, the method foo() in class B is called.

But in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual):

> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.

In my logic, CLR first finds `Foo()` is a virtual method, it looks into the method table of `D`, the runtime type, then it finds out there is an overriding member in this most derived class, it should call it and never realizes there is a `new Foo()` in the inheritance chain.

What's wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no derived class has overridden the member.

You're starting from the wrong place.  Your variable is of type `A` and contains an instance of `D`, so the virtual table used is `A`'s <sup>1</sup>.  Following the text above, we check for an overriding member.  We find one in `B`.  `C` does not count because it is not overriding, it is *shadowing* the base method.  And since `D` overrides `C`, not `A` or `B`, it doesn't count either.  We're looking for the overriding member in the most derived class.

So the method found is `B.Foo()`.

If you change `C` so it overrides instead of shadows, the found method will then be `D`, because it is the most derived overriding member.

If you instead change your object to an instance of `B` or `C`, `B.Foo()` will still be the chosen override.  To clarify, this is what I mean:

```
A tan = new B();
tan.Foo();    // which foo is called?  Why, the best Foo of course!  B!
```

The reason `B` is called is because the inheritance chain we are searching spans from `A` (the variable type)  to `B` (the runtime type).  `C` and `D` are no longer part of that chain, and are not part of the virtual table.

If we instead change the code to this:

```
C tan = new D();
tan.Foo();  // which foo, which foo?
```

The inheritance chain we search spans from `C` to `D`.  `D` is has an overriding member, so it's `Foo` is called.

Suppose you add another class `Q` that inherits from `A`, and `R` that inherits from `Q`, and so forth.  You have two branches of inheritance, right?  Which is chosen when searching for most derived type?  Follow the path from `A` (your variable type) to `D` (the runtime type).

I hope this makes sense.

<sup>1</sup> Not literally.  The virtual table belongs to `D` because it is the runtime type and contains everything in its chain of inheritance, but its useful and easier to think of `A` as the starting point.  You are searching for derived types, after all.

Answer (score 34):

Amy's answer is correct. Here's how I like to look at this question.

A virtual method is a *slot that can contain a method*.

When asked to do overload resolution, the *compiler* determines which *slot* to use *at compile time*.  But the *runtime* determines *what method is actually in that slot*.

Now with that in mind let's look at your example.

- `A` has one slot for `Foo`.
- `B` has one slot for `Foo`, inherited
  from `A`.
- `C` has two slots for `Foo`. One inherited from `B`, and
  one new. You said you wanted a *new* slot *named Foo*, so you got it.
- `D` has two slots for `Foo`, inherited from `C`.

That's the slots. So, what goes in those slots?

- In an `A`, `A.Foo` goes in the slot.
- In a `B`, `B.Foo` goes in the slot.
- In a `C`, `B.Foo` goes in the first slot and `C.Foo` goes in the second slot. Remember, these slots are *completely different*. You said you wanted two slots with the same name, so that's what you got. If that's confusing, that's your problem. Don't do that if it hurts when you do it.
- In a `D`, `B.Foo` goes in the first slot and `D.Foo` goes in the second slot.

So now what happens with your call?

The compiler reasons that you are calling `Foo` on something of compile time type `A`, so it finds the first (and only) `Foo` slot on `A`.

At runtime, the contents of that slot is `B.Foo`.

So that's what's called.

Make sense now?

Comment: What if there is an interface `ITest`, which contains a method `Bar()`. If a base class and its derived class both implement this interface, how many slots of `Bar()` are here in the derived class?

Comment: @ClaudeTan: An interface doesn't add a new slot. An interface *requires that such a slot exists*. Now, the exact details of which slot is the slot that is picked when you call the interface method are complicated; do a search on "interface reimplementation" for the details.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how much of this is an analogy, but how would this be applied to calling base implementations of a method? If, for example, `B`'s only `Foo` slot contained `B.Foo`, where does it go to find `A.Foo`?

Comment: @Rob The slots containing the methods is a simplification, they actually contain _pointers_ to the methods. If you call Foo() in a method of B, it will call the method pointed to by slot Foo. However, if you explicitly call A.Foo(), the compiler ignores the slots and inserts a direct call to the method A.Foo().

Comment: Another (metaphorical) way of thinking about it is that the `new` in the definition `class C:B` creates a `NewFoo()` and deletes the inherited `Foo()`. Then, it is more easily seen that it is this `NewFoo()` that is overridden in the definition of `class D:C`.

Comment: @Tomeamis: That's close but not *quite* right. C#, unlike C++, does not allow you to call A.Foo directly. It just allows you to call base.Foo. In that case it does *not* look at what is in the slot at all; it does a non-virtual call directly to A.Foo.  Now, isn't that what you just said?  Not exactly!

Comment: @Tomeamis: Here's a crazy scenario. You have three DLLs, X.DLL, Y.DLL, and Z.DLL, with classes X, Y and Z respectively, and Y : X, and Z : Y. X has virtual method Foo. Y does not override Foo. Z overrides Foo and calls base.Foo.  So X.Foo is called. Now suppose you replace Y.DLL with a *different* Y.DLL in which Y *does* override X.Foo.  You don't recompile Z.DLL. What happens when you run Z.Foo? Does it call X.Foo or Y.Foo? What do you think *should* happen?  What actually *does* happen, and why?