# I don't quite get casting in C#

Tags: c#

```
Class A
{
    string name = "a"; 
    public virtual void Rename(){//rename name to aaa}
}

Class B:A
{
    string name = "b";
    public override void Rename(){//rename name to bbb}
}

void Main()
{
    B objB  = new B();
    A objA  = objB as A;
    print(objB.name);// b
    print(objA.name);// a
    objA.Rename();
    print(objB.name);// bbb
    print(objA.name);// a
}
```

Why when I use `objA.Rename()`, it actually uses the override version written in class B. What is `objA` in the end. If it is A, then why it uses the override version. If it is B then why `objA.name` is a not bbb;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will CLR check the whole inheritance chain to determine which virtual method to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872841/will-clr-check-the-whole-inheritance-chain-to-determine-which-virtual-method-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object never changes. In memory, it is always a `B`, no matter how you choose to interact with it. The way to know this is the case is to just call `.GetType()` on your variables and they will all tell you each one is an instance of `B`.

```
B objB  = new B();
A objA  = objB as A;
Console.WriteLine(objB.GetType()) // B
Console.WriteLine(objA.GetType()) // B
```

The reason you get `"a"` at the end, is because you have two *different* declarations of `name`. meaning: `A.name` is a totally *different* address than `B.name`

To fix this, you could just remove `string name = "b";` from `B` and instead put `name = "b";` into it's constructor.

```
Class A
{
    string name = "a"; 
    public virtual void Rename(){//rename name to aaa}
}

Class B:A
{
    public override void Rename(){//rename name to bbb}
    public B() { name = "b"; }
}
```

Another way to think about this is that if you call `base.name` inside of `B` i am sure you will get the same result of `"a"`, showing you that `B` actually has two separate declarations of `name`.

Comment: Adding on to my question, if I do something like this Class A{string aName = "a";} Class B:A{string bName = "b";}   B objB = new B(); A objA = objB as A; then, if the object is always the same, why objA does not have a definition of bName?

Comment: @HaoyuLi because the reference is of type `A` and type `A` doesn’t know about any specific implementation of type `B`. Again, don’t confuse the type of the object with the type of the reference, they are not the same thing.

Comment: @HaoyuLi The object itself is *always* a `B` in *memory*, but that doesn't mean it is always a `B` in the way you interact with it. In your case, by casting it you are *choosing* to interact with it as if it was an `A`, but behind the scenes it is actually a `B`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must understand that casting in c# is a name that is used for very different conversions and can create confusion.

The casting you are asking about is technically named a *reference conversion*. Reference conversions are identity preserving conversions, this means that the object *does not change*, what changes is the type of the reference:

```
var s = “Hello”;
var o = (object)s;
var b = ReferenceEquals(s, o); //returns true
```

Here, `s` and `o` refer to the exact same object, the only thing that changes is the type of the reference.

It’s important to note that reference conversions are automatically provided by the compiler, you can’t define a user defined identity preserving conversion, you will get a compiler error.

What are the most common reference conversions you will encounter? Any conversion between types and subtypes or types and implemented interfaces, etc.

Now consider the following seemingly similar code:

```
var l = 1L;
var i = (int)l;
```

This code is *radically* different than the previous one. Why? Because the cast here *is not a reference conversion*. This actually calls a user defined `explicit` cast operator implemented in `System.Int32`. `i` and `l` are *different* objects.

Another important conversions in c# are boxing and unboxing conversions. These are not identity preserving but they do share common ”feature” as far as not being able to implement user defined boxing or unboxing conversions. Boxing refers to converting a value type into a assignment compatible reference type and unboxing is the opposite operation:

```
var i = 1;
var o = (object)i; //boxing
var ii = (int)o; //unboxing
```

How do you know at first glance if it’s a reference conversion or not? Well, as long as you know the hierarchy of the involved types. interfaces, etc. you should be able to reason it out.

Comment: I get it but when do we need to convert reference types? If the object does not change, why not just use that object? Why do we need or want to cast it as another reference type?

Comment: @HaoyuLi imagine you have a method that knows how to feed any animal, and you wants to call it for cats, dogs and elephants. Do you really want to write over and over essentially the *same* method for *each* animal you might have or isn’t it easier to just write one for base type `Animal`? Reference conversions are at the heart of polymorphism, a basic feature and tool of any Object Oriented Language.

Comment: I get it I think. I will practice more and learn along the way.