# C# method override resolution weirdness

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.Foo(int)");
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.Foo(int)");
    }

    public void Foo(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.Foo(object)");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int i = 10;
        d.Foo(i);
    }
}
```

And the surprising output is:

```
Derived.Foo(object)
```

I would expect it to select the overridden `Foo(int x)` method, since it's more specific. However, C# compiler picks the non-inherited `Foo(object o)` version. This also causes a boxing operation.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I've read this same question a few days ago, but can't find it anymore. The main point is, the compiler first checks for matching _instance_ methods. The overridden methods still coutn as _declared by the base class_, so they would only be considered if there was no matching method declared in `Derived`, but `Foo(object)` does match. There was a blog by Jon Skeet (or maybe Eric Lippert) about that, still trying to find it

Comment: @RenéVogt: are you sure it's the compiler that checks it or the runtime?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, the compiler. Found Jon Skeet's blog: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx scroll down to "Inheritance".

Comment: @RenéVogt: i don't think it's that simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872956/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter but that doesn't matter here, we don't talk about virtual methods because the compiler already choose to use the non-virtual instance method `Foo(object)`. If this wouldn't exist, it would choose the virtual method and then the things you linked would happen at runtime.

Comment: Btw, here is a fiddle that shows OP's code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7HJ6L If you uncomment the overloaded method it will be called and the output will be: _"Derived.Foo(object)"_

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the rule, and you may not like it...

> **Quote from [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933724/1612975)**
>
> if any method on a more-derived class is an applicable candidate, it
>   is automatically better than any method on a less-derived class, even
>   if the less-derived method has a better signature match.

The reason is because the method (that is a better signature match) might have been added in a later version and thereby be introducing a "[brittle base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class)" failure

---

***Note*** : This is a fairly complicated/in-depth part of the C# specs and it jumps all over the place. However, the main parts of the issue you are experiencing are written as follows

## Update

And this is why i like stackoverflow, It is such a great place to learn.

I was quoting the the section on **the run time processing of the method call**. Where as the question is about **compile time overload resolution**, and should be.

> **7.6.5.1 Method invocations**
>
> ...
>
> **The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from
>   the most derived types: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the
>   type in which the method F is declared, all methods declared in a base
>   type of C are removed from the set**. Furthermore, if C is a class type
>   other than object, all methods declared in an interface type are
>   removed from the set. (This latter rule only has affect when the
>   method group was the result of a member lookup on a type parameter
>   having an effective base class other than object and a non-empty
>   effective interface set.)

Please see Eric's post answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52670391/1612975 for a full detail on whats going on here and the appropriate part of the specs

## Original

**C#
Language Specification
Version 5.0**

> **7.5.5 Function member invocation**
>
> ...
>
> The run-time processing of a function member invocation consists of
>   the following steps, where M is the function member and, if M is an
>   instance member, E is the instance expression:
>
> ...
>
> If M is an instance function member declared in a reference-type:
>
> - E is evaluated. If this evaluation causes an exception, then no further steps are executed.
> - The argument list is evaluated as described in §7.5.1.
> - If the type of E is a value-type, a boxing conversion (§4.3.1) is performed to convert E to type object, and E is considered to be of
>     type object in the following steps. In this case, M could only be a
>     member of System.Object.
> - The value of E is checked to be valid. If the value of E is null, a System.NullReferenceException is thrown and no further steps are
>     executed.
> - The function member implementation to invoke is determined:
>
>   - **If the binding-time type of E is an interface, the function member to invoke is the implementation of M provided by the run-time
>       type of the instance referenced by E**. This function member is
>       determined by applying the interface mapping rules (§13.4.4) to
>       determine the implementation of M provided by the run-time type of the
>       instance referenced by E.
>   - **Otherwise, if M is a virtual function member, the function member to invoke is the implementation of M provided by the run-time type of
>       the instance referenced by E. This function member is determined by
>       applying the rules for determining the most derived implementation
>       (§10.6.3) of M with respect to the run-time type of the instance
>       referenced by E.**
>   - Otherwise, M is a non-virtual function member, and the function member to invoke is M itself.

After reading the specs what's interesting is, if you use an interface which describes the method, the compiler will choose the overload signature, in-turn working as expected

```
  public interface ITest
  {
     void Foo(int x);
  }
```

[Which can be shown here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D2HsAb)

In regards to the interface, it does make sense when considering the overloading behavior was implemented to protect against Brittle base class

---

**Additional Resources**

[Eric Lippert, Closer is better](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/#more-1806)

> The aspect of overload resolution in C# I want to talk about today is
>   really the fundamental rule by which one potential overload is judged
>   to be better than another for a given call site: closer is always
>   better than farther away. There are a number of ways to characterize
>   “closeness” in C#. Let’s start with the closest and move our way out:
>
> - A method first declared in a derived class is closer than a method first declared in a base class.
> - A method in a nested class is closer than a method in a containing class.
> - Any method of the receiving type is closer than any extension method.
> - An extension method found in a class in a nested namespace is closer than an extension method found in a class in an outer namespace.
> - An extension method found in a class in the current namespace is closer than an extension method found in a class in a namespace
>     mentioned by a using directive.
> - An extension method found in a class in a namespace mentioned in a using directive where the directive is in a nested namespace is closer
>     than an extension method found in a class in a namespace mentioned in
>     a using directive where the directive is in an outer namespace.

Comment: I honestly don’t understand how the spec applies to OP’s situation since *`Derived` explicitly overrides `Foo(int x)`*. So `Foo(int)` is *as close as* `Foo(object)` for the purpose of overload resolution in the `d.foo(i)` call. I’d agree if `Derived` hadn’t overridden the base class method but this isn’t the case here. Eric Lippert’s clarification does apply since it explicitly talks about “first *declared*”. But this doesn’t seem to be borne out by the specs, and is at any rate not really justified by his “brittle base class” rationale.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Whether a class *overrides* a method or not is an *implementation detail* of that class. Your proposal is basically that *if I change whether or not a class overrides a method, that changes how overload resolution works*, and that is a brittle base class failure! Think about it this way: suppose I have classes A, B, C, D, where D : C, C : B, B : A.  Suppose A declares a virtual method M, and C overrides it. You're telling me that *overload resolution for D.M might change if I move the override from C to B*.  That's a bad user experience.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Now, your point "I don't understand how the spec applies" is well taken, and that's because Saruman has quoted the wrong section of the spec. That's the section on the **run time processing** of the method call. The question is about **compile time overload resolution**.

Comment: @Saruman, the section of the spec you should have quoted is the one that reads **The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from the most derived types: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the type in which the method F is declared, all methods declared in a base type of C are removed from the set.** Note that as KonradRudolph notes, the "declared" is the important part there.

Comment: @EricLippert I disagree that it’s fundamentally/necessarily an implementation detail — this may well be the case in C# (mouth of horse, etc.) but it’s certainly not the case in other languages (e.g. C++), which do not suffer from the brittle base class case either.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, C# and C++ are different. First, C# was intended to address design shortcomings of C++, and this is one of them. Second, in my experience it is very common to have *all* the source code of a C++ program in front of you when you derive from a base class. In C# it is very common to derive from a base class in a library where all you have is metadata. In the C# scenario it is much more likely that you'd view overriding decisions as implementation details rather than as artifacts directly visible in the code you're reading.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is correct (excepting the fact that it quotes the wrong section of the spec) but it explains things from the perspective of the specification rather than giving a *justification* for why the specification is good.

Let's suppose we have base class B and derived class D.  B has a method M that takes Giraffe.  Now, remember, **by assumption, the author of D knows everything about B's public and protected members**.  Put another way: the author of D must know *more* than the author of B, because *D was written after B*, and *D was written to extend B to a scenario not already handled by B*.  We should therefore trust that the author of D is doing a *better* job of implementing *all* functionality of D than the author of B.

If the author of D makes an overload of M that takes an Animal, they are saying **I know better than the author of B how to deal with Animals, and that includes Giraffes**.  We we should expect overload resolution when given a call to D.M(Giraffe) to call D.M(Animal), and not B.M(Giraffe).

Let's put this another way:  We are given two possible justifications:

- A call to D.M(Giraffe) should go to B.M(Giraffe) because Giraffe is more specific than Animal
- A call to D.M(Giraffe) should go to D.M(Animal) because D is more specific than B

Both justifications are about *specificity*, so which justification is better? **We're not calling any method on Animal**! We're calling the method on D, so *that* specificity should be the one that wins.  The specificity of the *receiver* is far, far more important than the specificity of any of its parameters.  **The parameter types are there for tie breaking**.  The important thing is making sure we choose the most specific *receiver* because *that method was written later by someone with more knowledge of the scenario that D is intended to handle*.

Now, you might say, what if the author of D has also overridden B.M(Giraffe)? There are two arguments why a call to D.M(Giraffe) should call D.M(Animal) in this case.

*First*, the author of D should know that D.M(Animal) *can be called with a Giraffe*, and it must be written do the *right thing*.  So it should not matter from the user's perspective whether the call is resolved to D.M(Animal) or B.M(Giraffe), because D has been written correctly to do the right thing.

*Second*, whether the author of D has overridden a method of B or not is an *implementation detail* of D, and not *part of the public surface area*. Put another way: it would be very strange if *changing whether or not a method was overridden* changes *which method is chosen*.  Imagine if you're calling a method on some base class in one version, and then in the next version the author of the base class makes a minor change to whether a method is overridden or not; you would not expect overload resolution *in the derived class* to change.  C# has been designed carefully to prevent this kind of failure.

Comment: Very elegant and eloquent description, and thanks for the comments and corrections... I am always honored to be corrected by you and read your posts.