# Overloading an overriden method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

Is it possible to implement multiple overloaded methods in a derived class that would be called like an overriden method? I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Short example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Do(object o)
    {
        DoNothing();
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Do(object o)
    {
        Write("Something");
    }
    
    public void Do(string s) //override?, new?
    {
        Write(s);
    }
}
```

I know I can call Do(string s) from derived object:

```
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
c.Do("text");
```

result: `"text"`

but it will call `Do(object o)` when we are overriding

```
BaseClass c = new ChildClass();
c.Do("text");
```

result: `"Something"`

I was hoping I could avoid doing this:

```
public override void Do(object o)
    {
        if (o is string)
            Write(s);
        else
            Write("Something");
    }
```

Comment: If you want `BaseClass` to offer `Do(object)` *and* `Do(string)` then you have to define it there as well.

Comment: `Base.Do` will always call the `Do` method from the inheritance hierarchy. `Base` does not know anything about method defined in the descendants. So in short - it is not possible to affect this behavior in `Child` except for changing the override (or defining appropriate methods in `Base`).

Comment: You're overloading `ChildClass.Do`, not `BaseClass.Do`. Besides, `BaseClass c` explicitly says you want to use *Base*class methods only

Comment: Note that it can be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you please explain in more detail your real life case?

Comment: You could define the new method as an *extension* method on `BaseClass`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will CLR check the whole inheritance chain to determine which virtual method to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872841/will-clr-check-the-whole-inheritance-chain-to-determine-which-virtual-method-to)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, because virtual method call at a runtime is roughly speaking a call to a method at a given 'slot' number in a 'vtable' of a runtime type of the object (VTable is a table of methods for a particular type, [link to vtable  CLR source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/methodtable.h#L1245)). So slot number points to a specific method, it cannot be mapped to two or more methods in derived class.

As a workaround, you may use `dynamic` instance as below, but it will be significantly slower:

```
BaseClass a = new ChildClass();
a.Do(""); // invokes ChildClass.Do(object)
dynamic b = new ChildClass();
b.Do(""); // invokes ChildClass.Do(string)
```